# Measurement - get full unit name

Tags: swift, measurement

I'm not sure how to use measurement to get full name of the unit. For example "kilometers" instead of "km".

```
let measurement = Measurement(value: 50, unit: UnitLength.meters)
let convertedMeasurement = measurement.converted(to: UnitLength.kilometers)

let value = convertedMeasurement.value // 0.05
let unitSymbol = convertedMeasurement.unit.symbol // km
let unit = convertedMeasurement.unit.? // I expect the output to be "kilometers"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to get the full name of the unit you can use the `MeasurementFormatter` like so:

```
let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
formatter.unitStyle = .long
let unit = formatter.string(from: convertedMeasurement.unit) //"kilometers"
```

Comment: Isn't that a bit of over engineering to have in fact another formatter here..? It should rather be a property of the `unit` inside `measurement` to access a full name of the unit for my logic, especially if there's a way to get a `symbol` out of it.

Comment: You have a `Measurement`, but as far as I can see you don't have a `MeasurementFormatter` yet.  As for whether or not the full measurement name should be stored as part of the `Unit` you'll have to talk to Apple about that.  Overall this seems like a pretty painless solution.

Comment: "It should rather be a property of the unit inside measurement to access a full name of the unit for my logic, especially if there's a way to get a symbol out of it." -- This isn't true at all. How would it handle localization? That's the job of a formatter. Full names have different spellings (even different alphabets) in different languages. But the "SI symbol" is the standardized, so that's ok to be in the unit itself.

Comment: @Vive Formatting things as strings usually involves a bunch of parameters, and a local of internationalization-related complexity. Rather than crowding the API of things like `Double`, `NSNumber`, `NSDecimal`, `Measurement`, etc., the logic is extracted out into `Formatter` classes. That way, `Measurement` stays focused on measurement, and `MeasurementFormatter` stays focused on formatting.

Comment: It wasn't obvious to me, at first glance, but the above answer is NOT formatting a converted `Measurement`, it's formatting the `UnitLength` of the `Measurement`.  he answer is 100% correct.  it calls through to:

`MeasurementFormatter().string(from: UnitLength.kilometers)`

Comment: Might also be helpful to note that if you're using the formatted string as a title for a button or menu item, you can use [localizedCapitalized](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/localizedcapitalized) to get it properly capitalized, like "kilometers" to "Kilometers".